# can we open pdf using https URL using UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, https

I'm making an application in which my application needs to using  an https URLS.I want to display PDF File using https url in view(or)UIWebview. how do i do that? Please explain me ...Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

NSError *error;

DisplayPdfViewController *pdf=[[DisplayPdfViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdf animated:YES];

if (indexPath.row==0) 

{

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:sampleurl"];

 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];

NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[pdf.webView loadRequest:request];

//  pdf.title=[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

 else if (indexPath.row==1)

{

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https: some sample url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];

 NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [pdf.webView loadRequest:request];

 //  pdf.title=[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 }

else if (indexPath.row==2)

{

 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https: some sample url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];

NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [pdf.webView loadRequest:request];

//   pdf.title=[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}


else if (indexPath.row==3)

{

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:some sample url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];

 NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[pdf.webView loadRequest:request];

// pdf.title=[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 }

}
```

Comment: how will u load the normal url pdf(http)...same way u do it...whats the big deal in this?

Comment: same way i had proceed.But pdf should not be displayed.Blank screen will be displayed.

Comment: @murthy chimalakonda what you want in this ?

Comment: Https url used for some secured purpose.Thats why i think some procedure is having.But i dont no.whats the procedure.

Comment: @MurthyChimalakonda...what is the url?..have u pasted and tried in ur browser?

Comment: i want to some guidance how to display pdf file using https url

Comment: ya i tried in my browser.ITS worked.

Comment: assign delegate to ur webview and do as i said..good luck

Comment: i assign uiwebviewdelegate in pdfviewcontroller class.still not displayed pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the web page manually and for that use `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`

Comment: ok But those URLS are not static URLS.Dynamic URLS.i mean PDF Files are updated.

Comment: @Murthy...try to trace your webview response by implementing delegate methods like - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error...

Comment: coder.I AM not getting any Errors.If i ran the app PDF should not be displayed.Blank screen will be displayed.

Comment: ur browser not giving any warnings before loading the pdf?...is this self-signed certificate?

Comment: the delegate method will not get called in case of any error what u prefer.basically it gets called when the webview fails to make a request...

Comment: my browser not giving any warning before loading the pdf.

Comment: have u assigned ur webview to any UIWebView's delegate methods?

Comment: assign it to delegate...and use http://pastebin.com/MsHXqRHk code..and tell what its printing

Comment: i am not using any uiwebview.just To display pdfs uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Oh my goodness...how ur loading it in uiviewcontroller?...that too with the url???...but the title of ur question is showing me as ur using webview...

Comment: ok friend.But i menctioned the above code.How can i proceed.how to display pdf using https urls??using uiwebview or something.give me any idea or sample tutorial